# Meteor vue tracker not fetching reactive data

Tags: vue.js, meteor

I am using meteor with vue and using meteor-vue-tracker for reactive data. When i returning a collection from the tracker the data comes first two time as empty array and third time with the data. But in some of my vue component the tracker only run for two time since i am getting data only on third time the data returns as empty array in the particular component. Why this happens any idea? How many times meteor tracker run by default and how can we force tracker to run ?

Sample code:

```
meteor: {
        $subscribe: {
            'notes': []
        },
        async dataTrack() {
            if(Meteor.status().connected){
                this.data = Notes.find().fetch();
            }else{
                if(this.$pouch){
                    this.data = await this.$pouch.find({
                                        selector: {
                                            _id: {$gte: null}
                                        },
                                    },'notes').then(function(result){
                                        return result.docs;
                                    });
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal code example that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Sample code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue tracker normally runs two times without subscribing to a collection. If we subscribe to a collection with meteor vue tracker it runs three times. In my case there was no equivalent publication for the subscription.